# Regex: How to parse images not only the <img> tags

Tags: regex, image

For the last whole week I have been busting my head to find a Regular Expression which could parse all the images in a html source file. I know that there are many out there but mainly they parse the  tags. The tricky part is sometimes the images are in javascript and sometimes they have weird long formats such as :

```
http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.designscene.net/2015/07/binx-walton-josephine-le-tutour-vera-wang.html&amp;media=http://www.designscene.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Vera-Wang-Fall-Winter-2015-Patrick-Demarchelier-03-620x806.jpg&amp;description=Binx Walton and Josephine Le Tutour for Vera Wang FW15
```

I have tried negative look heads and booleans but could not find a good solution. Please give me a perspective.

Comment: BTW, for a reference I am working on this page : http://www.designscene.net/2015/07/daria-werbowy-equipment-fw15.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you said there are many ways to do that and to be honest there is not a regex solution which could parse all the html files out there.. I have tried it in the past as well. For me the below worked the best :

```
/(?:.(?!http|\,))+(\.jpg|\.png)
```

A bit of an explanation:

/......(.jpg|.png)  starts from the first slash it finds until finds an image ext
. any char between the slash and the ext
(?:.(?!http|\,))+ omit if there is http or , in it (works like a charm for the example link you have given

Hope it helps, regex is a very complex world. You can write the same exp in so many different ways. May be there is a better solution then I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?
https://regex101.com/r/jP4tV7/4

```
(http[^&"']+(?:jpg|gif|jpeg|png))(?:\&|'|")
```

Comment: Thanks Zolo, nice but your regex found 5 images on the reference page i gave, Koray's found 82 images. To be honest by looking at the expression I can not tell the difference :)

Comment: I'm testing/tested my regexp on your 1 line example, where not even an  <img> tag is presents. If you could show few kind of example lines, it would be easier to write a regexp for those.

Comment: can you also explain it for me, i see that you have edited your answer now finds 50 images.

Comment: designscene.net/2015/07/daria-werbowy-equipment-fw15.html  is the page that I am working on.. But sometimes links do not have full paths like : "/images/posts/2015/xxxx.jpg" I need the grab them as well.

Comment: Right now I don't have access to linux shell where I could test it and this regex page can't handle the whole source of your url with longer regexps. 
["']([^"']+(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))
This would be my final idea. If this works or works better or you would need the explanation anyway, let me know which one you are interested and I will explain it/them. (maybe you need to escape ("\" the ' or " characters according your code.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to search for any url that ends in an image-extension. This quick and dirty expression should do it

```
(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})[\/\w \.-]*(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|tif|tiff)
```

Available at: http://regexr.com/3bg8o

Comment: Thanks, just got 4 results.

Comment: Changed it to (/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})[\/\w \.-]*(jpg|png|svg) so that it is similar to Koray's answer and got 81 images.. Can you explain yours a bit. Exp is a bit complicated for my level

Comment: Ah. Didn't see your reference. I amended with a few extensions and bumped it up to 50.

Comment: Mostly ripped from :http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149 and amended to require an image-extension.